# Помогите пожалуйста, как это можно сделать?

Tags: c++

> 1. Одномерный массив из 10 элементов заполнить числовыми значениями.
> 2. Определить произведение положительных значений.
> 3. Вывести номера локальных максимумов, т.е. таких `Ai`, что `A i-1 < Ai >A i+1`

Я сделал вернюю часть, а как можно сделать проверку локальных максимумов? Можно ли сделать более компактной, через цикл?

```
#include <iostream> 

int main() 
{ 
    using namespace std; 
    const int n = 10; 
    int i = 0, an[n] = { 25,3,16,-2,1,10,12,10,-10,2 }; 
    float b = 0, k = 0; 
    for (; i < n; i++) 
        if(an[i] >= 0) 
            b = an[i] + b; 
    cout << b; 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: В том же цикле, который у Вас уже есть сравнивать каждый элемент с двумя соседними, и если он больше соседей - печатать. Главное, не забудьте учесть, что у первого и последнего элемента по одному соседу

Comment: А такое как обрабатывать: `-2 0 0 0 -1`? Ну, несколько одинаковых значений? Что тогда выводить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int max = an[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        if(an[i] > an[i+1] && an[i] > an[i-1])
        {
            max = an[i];
            cout << "Локальные максимумы: " << max << endl;
        }
    }
```